# Normalize data with a variance-shift in measurement-error to achieve high correlation with true underlying process?

Tags: time-series, normalization, measurement-error, timeseries-segmentation

I am discussing the question whether to normalize the data or not in the following setting:

I have a true time series
$$s_t = iid(0,\sigma_s^2)$$
however I only observe different $$\hat{s}_{t,i} = s_t + v_t$$ where $i$ are different sources and if $t \le T_b$: $$i=1,...,n \\ v_t = iid(0, \sigma_h^2)$$ and if $t > T_b$: $$ i = 1,...,m \\ v_t = iid(0, \sigma_l^2)$$ where $\sigma_h^2 > \sigma_l^2$ and $m > n$.
Hence, there is a break at $t = T_b$ lowering the variance (measurement error). Now, the question is should I normalize $\hat{s}_{t,i}$ individually pre and post break before aggregating to achieve the highest possible correlation of the averaged $\hat{s}_{t,i}$ with $s_t$? Or on what does the answer to this question depend?

Edit: I assume that $n < 10$ is quite small whereas $m$ is around 100.